# How to connect GCP, VM machine with WinSCP

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, ssh-keys, ssh-agent, winscp

I created Virtual machine (VM) instance in the GCP but unable to connect with WinSCP from the windows machine.

I created on VM instance in the GCP then generated pub key by using command ssh-keygen and upload in the WinSCP advanced-->SSH-->Authentication-->Private Key file. Then try to connect by user name but getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

To setup a public key authentication to GCE, you need to paste your public key to 
"Metadata" page of your project on Google Cloud Platform.

For details, see [WinSCP guide to connecting to GCE](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine).